# preg_replace add ; to javascript function

Tags: preg-replace

I have a javascript which contains something like this

```
var f = function(){
    if(){
    }else{
    }
}
```

and I need to add ; at the end, like this

```
var f = function(){
    if(){
    }else{
    }
};
```

I need some help to get the closing function } tag and not the } tags from inside the function.
Thanks

Comment: You'll need to loop over the string counting `{` and `}`s after a `function ()`, with some way to ignore strings and other literals which can have just the one.

Comment: Regular expressions aren't for this kind of task. What if - within the function body - is a Javascript regular expression containing more opening or closing braces?

Comment: @PaulS. The string "Hello, {world" breaks your thesis.

Comment: @LinusKleen is right, unless you happen to have perfect knowledge, say, that all indentation is exactly standard. Then you could probably do it. Otherwise, since this is not a regular grammar, regular expressions won't work.

Comment: @LinusKleen Yep, I edited my comment. You'd basically have to implement a JavaScript interpreter in php which is nearly as good as the one in a browser.

Comment: Not an interpreter, just a parser. It might be possible with a PHP "regular" expression, though, because they support recursion and lookbehinds and backreferences and all that fun stuff. @user1628151: Why do you need to do this? Is this the problem, or is this what you think is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, if all you can use is regex. It'd be very much like [parsing HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/781965).

Instead, see if you can find an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) parser for javascript in PHP - that's what you'll need to be able to find the appropriate closing bracket.